# need help regarding a packet capture program

Tags: timer, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, file-writing

The following is a program that captures TCP packets < port 80 > and prints header related information in the console for every packet. I have also included a timer , so that after every 1000 millisec i.e. 1 sec , the frequency of occurence of various flags , and distinct number of Src IPs , Ack nos and Seq nos encountered are written into a file. I'm working in fedora core 5. I am encountering the following problems :

1.file writing part works fine during some executions , but most of the other times ,in the same machine , the file is not at all written to.

2.When i execute this program in my house , about 30 packets are captured every second. But when i run the same program in  my lab , just 1 packet is captured per second. ( though i do the same amount of browsing in both places )

```
#define INTERVAL 1000        /* number of milliseconds to go off */

#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/time.h> // for setitimer
#include<unistd.h>    // for pause
#include <signal.h>     /* for signal */

/* default snap length (maximum bytes per packet to capture) */
#define SNAP_LEN 1518

/* ethernet headers are always exactly 14 bytes [1] */
#define SIZE_ETHERNET 14

/* Ethernet addresses are 6 bytes */
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN  6

/* Ethernet header */
struct sniff_ethernet {
        u_char  ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* destination host address */
        u_char  ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* source host address */
        u_short ether_type;                     /* IP? ARP? RARP? etc */
};

/* IP header */
struct sniff_ip {
        u_char  ip_vhl;                 /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
        u_char  ip_tos;                 /* type of service */
        u_short ip_len;                 /* total length */
        u_short ip_id;                  /* identification */
        u_short ip_off;                 /* fragment offset field */
        #define IP_RF 0x8000            /* reserved fragment flag */
        #define IP_DF 0x4000            /* dont fragment flag */
        #define IP_MF 0x2000            /* more fragments flag */
        #define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff       /* mask for fragmenting bits */
        u_char  ip_ttl;                 /* time to live */
        u_char  ip_p;                   /* protocol */
        u_short ip_sum;                 /* checksum */
        struct  in_addr ip_src,ip_dst;  /* source and dest address */
};
#define IP_HL(ip)               (((ip)->ip_vhl) & 0x0f)
#define IP_V(ip)                (((ip)->ip_vhl) >> 4)

/* TCP header */
typedef u_int tcp_seq;

struct sniff_tcp {
        u_short th_sport;               /* source port */
        u_short th_dport;               /* destination port */
        tcp_seq th_seq;                 /* sequence number */
        tcp_seq th_ack;                 /* acknowledgement number */
        u_char  th_offx2;               /* data offset, rsvd */
#define TH_OFF(th)      (((th)->th_offx2 & 0xf0) >> 4)
        u_char  th_flags;
        #define TH_FIN  0x01
        #define TH_SYN  0x02
        #define TH_RST  0x04
        #define TH_PUSH 0x08
        #define TH_ACK  0x10
        #define TH_URG  0x20
        #define TH_ECE  0x40
        #define TH_CWR  0x80
        #define TH_FLAGS        (TH_FIN|TH_SYN|TH_RST|TH_ACK|TH_URG|TH_ECE|TH_CWR)
        u_short th_win;                 /* window */
        u_short th_sum;                 /* checksum */
        u_short th_urp;                 /* urgent pointer */
};

u_short sport[100];int spd=0;
u_int seq[100];int seqd=0;
u_short win[100];int wind=0;

FILE* urlfile;
int count = 1,flag=0,t=0; 
float sc=0,ac=0,fc=0,pc=0,uc=0,rc=0;

void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet);

void
print_payload(const u_char *payload, int len);

void
print_hex_ascii_line(const u_char *payload, int len, int offset);



void
print_app_usage(void);

void DoStuff(void);

void DoStuff(void) {
    t++;
  printf("Timer %d went off.########################################\n",t);
 // fprintf(urlfile,"\n hi hi");
  fprintf(urlfile,"\ntime %d 1:%f 2:%f 3:%f 4:%f 5:%f 6:%f 7:%f 8:%f 9:%f",t,sc/count,ac/count,fc/count,pc/count,uc/count,rc/count,(float)spd/count,(float)wind/count,(float)seqd/count);
  printf("\ntime %d 1:%f 2:%f 3:%f 4:%f 5:%f 6:%f 7:%f 8:%f 9:%f",t,sc/count,ac/count,fc/count,pc/count,uc/count,rc/count,(float)spd/count,(float)wind/count,(float)seqd/count);
  printf("\n a_count : %f , total_packets : %d , frequency : %f",ac,count,ac/count);
  printf("\n r_count : %f , total_packets : %d , frequency : %f",rc,count,rc/count);
  printf("\n p_count : %f , total_packets : %d , frequency : %f",pc,count,pc/count);
  printf("\n s_count : %f , total_packets : %d , frequency : %f",sc,count,sc/count);
  printf("\n u_count : %f , total_packets : %d , frequency : %f",uc,count,uc/count);
  printf("\n f_count : %f , total_packets : %d , frequency : %f",fc,count,fc/count);
  printf("\ncount of distinct seq nos : %d no/pcount : %f ",seqd,(float)seqd/count);
  printf("\ncount of distinct sports : %d no/pcount : %f ",spd,(float)spd/count);
  printf("\ncount of distinct win nos : %d no/pcount : %f\n\n ",wind,(float)wind/count);
  ac=rc=pc=fc=sc=uc=0;count=1;  
  spd=seqd=wind=0;
}


void
print_app_usage(void)
{

    printf("Usage: ./a.out [interface]\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Options:\n");
    printf("    interface    Listen on <interface> for packets.\n");
    printf("\n");

return;
}


/*
 * dissect/print packet
 */
void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{

                      /* packet counter */
    int j;
    /* declare pointers to packet headers */
    const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet;  /* The ethernet header [1] */
    const struct sniff_ip *ip;              /* The IP header */
    const struct sniff_tcp *tcp;            /* The TCP header */
    const char *payload;                    /* Packet payload */

    int size_ip;
    int size_tcp;
    int size_payload;

    printf("\nPacket number %d:\n", count);
    count++;

    /* define ethernet header */
    ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);

    /* define/compute ip header offset */
    ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
    size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;
    if (size_ip < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
        return;
    }

    switch(ip->ip_p) {
        case IPPROTO_TCP:
            printf("   Protocol: TCP\n");
            break;
        case IPPROTO_UDP:
            printf("   Protocol: UDP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_ICMP:
            printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_IP:
            printf("   Protocol: IP\n");
            return;
        default:
            printf("   Protocol: unknown\n");
            return;
    }

    /* define/compute tcp header offset */
    tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
    size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
    if (size_tcp < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid TCP header length: %u bytes\n", size_tcp);
        return;
    }

    flag=0;
    for(j=0;j<spd;j++)
    {      
       if(sport[j]==ntohs(tcp->th_sport)) { flag=1; break; }
    }
    if(flag==0) sport[spd++]=ntohs(tcp->th_sport);

    flag=0;
    for(j=0;j<seqd;j++)
    {      
       if(seq[j]==ntohs(tcp->th_seq)) { flag=1; break; }
    }
    if(flag==0) seq[seqd++]=ntohs(tcp->th_seq);

    flag=0;
    for(j=0;j<wind;j++)
    {      
       if(win[j]==ntohs(tcp->th_win)) { flag=1; break; }
    }
    if(flag==0) win[wind++]=ntohs(tcp->th_win);

    printf("   Src port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_sport));
    printf("   Window: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_win));
    printf("   Sequence no: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_seq));

    if (tcp->th_flags & TH_URG){
        printf("   Flag: TH_URG");uc++;
    }
    if (tcp->th_flags & TH_RST){
        printf("   Flag: TH_RST");rc++;
    }
    if (tcp->th_flags & TH_ACK){
        printf("   Flag: TH_ACK");ac++;
    }
    if (tcp->th_flags & TH_PUSH){
        printf("   Flag: TH_PUSH");pc++;
    }
    if (tcp->th_flags & TH_SYN){
        printf("   Flag: TH_SYN");sc++;
    }
    if (tcp->th_flags & TH_FIN){
        printf("   Flag: TH_FIN");fc++;
    }


    if (size_payload > 0) {
        printf("   Payload (%d bytes):\n", size_payload);

    }

return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *dev = NULL;           /* capture device name */
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];      /* error buffer */
    pcap_t *handle;             /* packet capture handle */
    char filter_exp[] = "tcp port 80";
    struct bpf_program fp;          /* compiled filter program (expression) */
    bpf_u_int32 mask;           /* subnet mask */
    bpf_u_int32 net;            /* ip */
    //int num_packets = 10;         /* number of packets to capture */

    /* check for capture device name on command-line */
    if (argc == 2) {
        dev = argv[1];
    }
    else if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: unrecognized command-line options\n\n");
        print_app_usage();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        /* find a capture device if not specified on command-line */
        dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
        if (dev == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n",
                errbuf);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* get network number and mask associated with capture device */
    if (pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n",
            dev, errbuf);
        net = 0;
        mask = 0;
    }

    /* print capture info */
    printf("Device: %s\n", dev);
    printf("Filter expression: %s\n", filter_exp);

    /* open capture device */
    handle = pcap_open_live(dev, SNAP_LEN, 1, 1000, errbuf);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* make sure we're capturing on an Ethernet device [2] */
    if (pcap_datalink(handle) != DLT_EN10MB) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is not an Ethernet\n", dev);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* compile the filter expression */
    if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n",
            filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* apply the compiled filter */
    if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n",
            filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    urlfile=fopen("output.txt","w");
    if(urlfile==NULL) printf("Unable to create file.");

    // timer code

    struct itimerval it_val;  /* for setting itimer */

  /* Upon SIGALRM, call DoStuff().
   * Set interval timer.  We want frequency in ms, 
   * but the setitimer call needs seconds and useconds. */
  if (signal(SIGALRM, (void (*)(int)) DoStuff) == SIG_ERR) {
    perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
    exit(1);
  }
  it_val.it_value.tv_sec =     INTERVAL/1000;
  it_val.it_value.tv_usec =    (INTERVAL*1000) % 1000000;   
  it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;
  if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("error calling setitimer()");
    exit(1);
  }

    /* now we can set our callback function */
    //pcap_loop(handle, num_packets, got_packet, NULL);
    pcap_loop(handle,-1, got_packet, NULL);// set num_packets to -1 to capture indefinitely.
    /* cleanup */
    pcap_freecode(&fp);
    pcap_close(handle);
    fclose(urlfile);
    printf("\nCapture complete.\n");

return 0;
}
```

As this is a part of my project , i'm right now stuck at this point.. Can anyone please suggest regarding what may have gone wrong.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you haven't told us the operating system or the hardware.

Comment: at home , the pgm listens to eth0 interface , and in the lab , it listens to em0 interface.. does this information suffice ..

Comment: in lab,  FreeBSD 7.0-RELEASE-p3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `fflush()`?

Comment: i tried after your suggestion,  this fflush() helped resolve the problem , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem no [2] , with just a small change in the filter expression : i changed it from "tcp port 80" to "tcp". And , now this program is working as well in my lab as it did at my home.

still , the problem no [1] is yet unresolved.. And moreover , The file writing is not keeping in pace with the console i/o.. By the time the console displays capture details for 120 seconds , the file has only around 90 second - data filled in.. I wonder if this is a general problem with file i/o..

Comment: Maybe there is a difference in Fedora/FreeBSD in relation to file i/o? Have you measured the timing on it on both platforms? Don't forget, there's other factors in play, paging, cpu load, running X?, packet sniffing can put a load on the cpu as well..